# is there a way in react native panGestures to disable scroll or drag when pinch gesture is active and the reverse way

Tags: react-native, d3.js, react-native-gesture-handler

I wanted a zoomable and scrollable map like screen, when i used PinchGestureHandler with a panResponder inside it in a View I'm not able to zoom. What's the best solution to fix this issue

Any library that can provide dragable and zoomable view

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.